# Cannot coerce type env to vector of type int

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to create **reactive ValueBox** using **sliderbar** and **groupcheckbox** input, but I am encountering an error while running the shiny app stating

> "cannot coerce type env to vector of type int"

I believe my error is while aggregating the value for ValueBox, but I don't know how to resolve it.

I tried using summarize and aggregate but still, the error persists I am not sure why and also, whether the aggregation is able to consider checkboxgroup multiple values to perform calculation or not!!

My code

```
   shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  ##Adding control widgets
  output$yearSlider <- renderUI({
    sliderInput(inputId = "year.in"
                ,label="Year Filter",min =yearmin,max =yearmax,step=1,
                value=c(yearmin,yearmax)
                ,ticks = T  ,sep=""   )  })
  output$catControls <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput('cat', label = "Accounts",
                       choices = cat, selected = cat) })           
  observe({
    if(input$reset != 0) {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "cat", choices = cat, selected=cat)
      updateSliderInput(session, "year.in", val = c(yearmin, yearmax))}
      })
  ##Reactivity
  df.filtered <- reactive({
    # Error handling 
    if (is.null(input$year.in) | 
        is.null(input$cat)     
            ) {
      return(NULL)
    } 
      df %>%
      filter(Year      >=   input$year.in[1],
             Year      <=   input$year.in[2],
             Ad.Account.Anonymised %in% input$cat,
             )    
  })        
  costs <- reactive({
    aggregate(df.filtered$Cost,by 
    =list(df.filtered$Year,df.filtered$Ad.Account.Anonymised),FUN=sum)
     #  df.filtered() %>%
    #  group_by(Year, Ad.Account.Anonymised) %>%
    #  summarize(cost.total = sum(Cost))
  })
    ##Plotting
  output$value1 <- renderValueBox({ 
    valueBox(
      formatC(costs(), format="d", big.mark=',')
      ,'Total Costs'
      ,icon = icon("gbp",lib='glyphicon')
      ,color = "green")  
  })
})
```

Sample data:

```
   Year      Ad.Account.Anonymised     Cost
   2017       A                         10
   2018       B                         20
   2018       A                         30
   2019       D                         40
```

Comment: reference reactive objects with parenthesis. Use `costs()` instead of `costs`.

Comment: @PaulvanOppen same error and still not working after using paranthesis

Comment: Another possible reason: in `updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "cat", choices = cat, selected=cat)` choices should be values. Do you mean: `updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "cat", choices = "cat", selected="cat")`? in your code I assume R will be looking for object `cat`. Does this object exist?

Comment: @PaulvanOppen choices and selected arguments looks for a list and "cat" using in quotes will throw an error if I use.   
Though I tried it is throwing error       

.Yes, cat object exist and it makes the groupcheckbox of Ad.Account.Anonymised

Comment: @PaulvanOppen now the error changed to that my category column is non numeric but it is non-numeric..
Any idea?